# Will this Selection Sort Code work in O(n) for best case?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, complexity-theory, selection-sort

I search everywhere on the internet for the best case time complexity of selection sort that is o(n^2). But i write and tested this below code of selection sort that can work in O(n) for best case (that is array is already sorted). Please find the mistake in this program

This is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
/* Function to print an array */
void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

void selectionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j, max_idx;

    // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        printArray(arr, n);

        // Find the minimum element in unsorted array
        max_idx = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (j = 1; j < n - i; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] >= arr[max_idx])
            {
                max_idx = j;
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count != n - i - 1)
        {   //swap only if not already sorted
            // Swap the found minimum element with the first element
            swap(&arr[max_idx], &arr[n - i - 1]);
        }
        else //already Sorted so returning
        {
            return;
        }
        //cout << "Sorted array: \n";
        printArray(arr, n);
    }
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    selectionSort(arr, n);
    cout << "Sorted array: \n";
    printArray(arr, n);
    return 0;
}

// This is code is contributed by www.bhattiacademy.com
```

Comment: Hmmm... just test with a small already sorted array.

Comment: Your solution will be O(n²) because you don't have an early stoping situation, try to add one.

Comment: A mistake in your program is that it says "minimum element" but really it's *maximum* element. Another mistake is to write your own `swap` function instead of just using the one provided by the library.

Comment: @SidoShiro92 What do you mean they don't have an early stoping situation?

Comment: @HeapOverflow Like in a sort if during an iteration you don't swap/move/insert any element, it means the array is already sorted and you can exit the function.

Comment: @SidoShiro92 But this code does that.

Comment: This if is the stoping condition after first iteration if array is already sorted:if (count != n - i - 1)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your algorithm has a best case running time of Θ(n), because if the array is already in ascending order then `count` will equal `n - 1` on the first iteration of the outer loop, so the algorithm will terminate early.

Your algorithm is different to the standard selection sort algorithm, which looks like this:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    int min_idx = i;
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if(arr[j] < arr[min_idx]) {
            min_idx = j;
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i], &arr[min_idx]);
}
```

The selection sort algorithm iteratively searches for the minimum remaining element and swaps it into place. This doesn't create an opportunity to detect that the array is already in increasing order, so there's no opportunity to terminate early, and selection sort's best case running time is therefore Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: It's mean selection sort can be modified (as in above) to make it's best case complexity of O(n). It's just a small check.

Comment: It can be, but that's not the standard selection sort algorithm. In practice the extra operations to maintain the counter would slow it down too much in the average case for it to be worth it in the rare case that the array is already sorted, and if you need a simple quadratic-time sorting algorithm then insertion sort is generally the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

Selection Sort: Idea  Given an array of n items
1.Find the largest item x, in the range of [0…n−1] 
2.Swap x with the (n−1)th item 
3.Reduce n by 1 and go to Step 1

Selection sort function you can use following algorithm has hint to write the code:
[image]

Comment: can you make Selection sort to work in O(n) for best case i.e already sorted array